# Loop to read shapefiles using readOGR

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-sp, rgdal

I have 500 shape files, containing points (lon/lat) data, and a border buffer.

I also have the following code to read each shapefile, join it with the buffer, compute some values, and then add those values to a data frame's column.

Here's my code:

```
    path="/Users/fun/Drought shapefiles/"


 file.names <- list.files(path, pattern="*.shp", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

#Now automate this process:
for (m in 1:500){
    dsn=path

    ##Load the buffer and the map:
Buffer <- readOGR("/Users/fun/Degrees Buffer Projections", "Germania buffer 10km")
Map <- readOGR("/Users/fun/Drought shapefiles/", m)

#Now convert the map into a dataframe and intersect it:
over(Map,as(Buffer,"SpatialPolygons"))
nrow(Map)
pts = Shapefile[!is.na(over(Shapefile,as(Buffer,"SpatialPolygons"))),]
nrow(pts)
head(pts@data)
plot(pts)

#Calculate the mean drought value across the border, and assign to a column:
drought_values <- pts$pdsi_440
drought.data[[2]][[m]] <- mean(drought_values)
}
```

My question pertains to the following line of code:

```
Map <- readOGR("/Users/fun/Drought shapefiles/", m)
```

I don't seem to have written the correct code here, in order to loop through the 500 files. What am I doing wrong.

For reference, the files have names like the following:

```
cru_drought_86_shape.shp
cru_drought_87_shape.shp
cru_drought_88_shape.shp
```

And so on...

If you'd like to see two of the shapefiles, here they are: 
[Drought 303](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx8qou73efj6owe/cru_drought_303_shape.shp?dl=0)
[Drought 304](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0t1qrjwak1gvac/cru_drought_304_shape.shp?dl=0)

Comment: you probably need to concatenate / paste the file path: `readOGR(paste0("/Users/fun/Drought shapefiles/", m))`

Comment: Can you provide minimal shape files?

Comment: That doesn't work, because the files are in the following format:

cru_drought_86_shape.shp
cru_drought_87_shape.shp
cru_drought_88_shape.shp

Sure I'll get the Shapefiles

Comment: @GIS_newb: you can try `Map <- readOGR(paste0("/Users/fun/Drought shapefiles", paste0("cru_drought_", m, "_shape"))`

Comment: @GIS_newb: also it's usually not a good idea to have "spaces" in folder and file names especially when working with spatial data. See more https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/advantages-of-using-underscores-in-arcgis-file-naming-conventions

Comment: @GIS_newb: and you need to share more than just `.shp` files e.g. `shx`, `sbx`, .etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your for loop you are passing a number from 1:500 (m). If you want to do this, you need to use the number to index a list of filenames. Since you have used the full.names = T argument, then you just pass the full filename:

```
 file.names <- list.files(path, pattern="*.shp", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

for (m in 1:500){
Map <- readOGR(file.names[m])
}
```